# Convergence of a generic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

So I have a sequence $\epsilon(n)$ that converge to 0 when $n$ goes to infinity. What can I say about the series for $n \rightarrow \infty$ 
$$\sum{\frac{\epsilon(n)}{n}}?$$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wolfram says $\frac1{n\log n}$ does not converge.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando in fact all series of the form $\frac{1}{n\left(\log n\right)^p}$ diverge for $p\leq 1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#ln-series

Comment: But why provide infinitely many counterexamples, when one does the trick? :P

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.  The series will converge if $\epsilon(n) = 1/n$, and will diverge if $\epsilon(n) = 1 / \log(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\epsilon(n)=0$, the series could (i) converge absolutely, (ii) diverge, or (iii) converge conditionally.

If $\epsilon(n)=\frac1n$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is seen to converge absolutely by using, for example, the integral test.

If $\epsilon(n)=\frac{1}{\log(n)}$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ is seen to diverge, by using, again for example, the integral test.

And if $\epsilon(n)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\log(n)}$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n\log(n)}$ converges conditionally using Leibniz's test.

Comment: Please let me know how i can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark